# How to compare variable (from command line) and string in Makefile?

Tags: if-statement, makefile, gnu-make

I trying to compare variable and string in Makefile for defining different actions depending on which value user appointed to variable from the command line. But every time I get an unexpected result.
Example:
*Makefile*

```
print:
ifeq ("minikube", $(env))
    @echo "yes"
else
    @echo "no"
endif
```

*Execution from shell*

```
$ make print env=minikube
no
```

Additional info
GNU Make version 4.2.1
GNU bash version 5.0.17
Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Remove the quotes around "minikube".

Comment: @rveerd Ouu, so simple, strange that I could not found this on any web resource.
Thank you very much!
This hint helped me

Comment: Quote is not a special symbol in make, it's treated same as anything else. They are in shell commands in the body of the recipes.